# Pricing Options on Inefficient/Illiquid Assets

Tags: options, pricing

I'm currently trying to gather more information on option pricing in very inefficient markets for the underlying. By inefficient, I mean markets with consequential bid-ask spreads (5% or more) and limited liquidity.

Do you have any resources that talk about this subject? I have tried finding research papers or talks about option pricing in such markets but I was not successful.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, I'm talking about the underlying having bid-ask spread of 5% or more, not the option market. I'm looking for any research paper or discussion that talk about option pricing in such markets.

Comment: There is a large literature on options pricing with transaction costs, e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2328113?seq=1, https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/zariphop/pdfs/TZ-7.pdf or https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s007800050046.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't looking with the key word "transaction cost".